# Info windows code

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem. I can't put each marker with info windows, neither the description

example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
var map

function initialize() {

    var centerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.697476,-9.207047);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12, 
        center: centerLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }   

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var placescoordjs = {{=XML(response.json(placescoord))}}
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < placescoordjs.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(placescoordjs[i][0],placescoordjs[i][1]),
            map: map
        }); 
    }   
}   

function mymarker() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{=coordenadas[0]}},{{=coordenadas[1]}});

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10, 
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }   

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map, 
        title:"My Marker!!"
    }); 
    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    marker.setMap(map);
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<html>https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisboa</html>"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

I have this code. I have a database that "puts" the markers in the map but how i can add each marker the description and a info windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the infoWindow, and bind it to the marker using google.maps.event.addListener...

it's all in the doc you've posted:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<html>your html</html>"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

try to update your initialize method to something like this:

```
function initialize() {

    var centerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.697476,-9.207047);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12, 
        center: centerLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }   

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var placescoordjs = {{=XML(response.json(placescoord))}}
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < placescoordjs.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(placescoordjs[i][0],placescoordjs[i][1]),
            map: map
        }); 

        /* Creates the infowindow */
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<html>your html</html>"
        });

        /* Bind the infowindow to the marker */
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: But if i do that it won't appear me the map window. It disappear.

Comment: sorry i don't get it... the infowindow only appears if you click the marker.

Comment: But i have 21 markers that i get from my database. If i click it won't appear nothing.

Comment: Done. I think that when i get the 21 markers on my map i have to add the info window as well..

Comment: Done (1 reputation me. :) )